# JRebel-JVMTI error when running spring server

Tags: java, spring, jrebel

I get this error when running Spring source code.

JRebel-JVMTI [FATAL] Couldn't write to C:\Users\���ȯ.jrebel\bootcache. Please make sure that this location exists and is writable, or specify another location by changing the 'rebel.base' system property.

Answer (score 2):

JRebel tries to create a directory for license, properties, logs and boot cache and by default it places it under `%USERPROFILE%/.jrebel` however in your case the path contains some unicode characters.

This is not properly supported so you will need to define a non-unicode path for the base folder via the VM argument `-Drebel.base=[path]` or the environment variable `REBEL_BASE=[path]`.

For example:

```
java -agentpath:C:/path/to/jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll -Drebel.base=C:/some/path foo.Main
```

This folder will be created if it does not exist.